# Unable to upgrade pip in docker build

Tags: docker, pip

In running the Docker build (using Jenkins CI), it fails on upgrading pip (last line of the docker file).  I need it to upgrade version 8.1.1, as it suggest in the log, as my deploy fails on PIP versions mismatch.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
FROM python:3.4   

# Expose a port for gunicorn to listen on
EXPOSE 8002

# Make a workdir and virtualenv
WORKDIR /opt/documents_api

# Install everything else
ADD . /opt/documents_api

# Set some environment varialbes for PIP installation and db management
ENV CQLENG_ALLOW_SCHEMA_MANAGEMENT="True"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Here's the error:

```
Step 15 : RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
19:46:00  ---> Running in 84e2bcc850c0
19:46:04 Collecting pip
19:46:04   Downloading pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
19:46:04 Installing collected packages: pip
19:46:04   Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
19:46:04     Uninstalling pip-7.1.2:
19:46:05       Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.2
19:46:10 Exception:
19:46:10 Traceback (most recent call last):
19:46:10   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 424, in _rmtree_safe_fd
19:46:10     os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
19:46:10 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pip'
19:46:10 You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
```

Comment: I used the same Dockerfile to run on my environment and it worked fine. Here is the output of logs: http://pastebin.com/4qAZLKH1. Everything went just fine. No errors, issues.

Comment: Try deleting the ubuntu:14.04 and python:3.4 image you have. Docker will download it again once you rebuild, maybe some issue there. For me, fresh images worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried just getting a runnable image without the pip upgrade, just so you can do _docker exec ... bash_ and attach to a shell to see where pip could have ended up - and with what name? I mostly use Centos based images with **both** Python2 and Python3, so I know that I end up with both pip2 and pip3, but Ubuntu based images may vary, based on which Python version you install.

Comment: This might be a long shot, but maybe the `--` in upgrade is causing a problem with the run statement, have you tried doing `RUN pip3 install -U pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out the host I was running had no outside (internet) access.  So the upgrade was failing.  We solved it by adding another package to the DTR that had the necessary version in it.

Answer (score 4):

When you use two `FROM` directives, docker creates two output images, that's why it's messed up.

First, remove `FROM ubuntu:14.04` and don't `apt-get update` in a Dockerfile, it's a bad practice (your image will be different every time you build, defeating the whole purpose of containers/Docker).

Second, you can check official `python` images Dockerfile to know which version of pip is installed, for example, [python:3.4](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/3232863ad5aba683fb084cb00097723c8c9efb47/3.4/Dockerfile) (it's already v8.1.1).

Third, there is a special image for you case (external application): [python:3.4-onbuild](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/7663560df7547e69d13b1b548675502f4e0917d1/3.4/onbuild/Dockerfile). Your Dockerfile can be reduced to:

```
FROM python:3.4-onbuild
ENV CQLENG_ALLOW_SCHEMA_MANAGEMENT="True"
EXPOSE 8002
CMD python myapp.py
```

One last thing, try to use alpine based images, they're much smaller (for python, it's [almost 10 time smaller](https://imagelayers.io/?images=python:3.5.1,python:3.5.1-onbuild,python:3.5.1-slim,python:3.5.1-alpine) than the ubuntu based).

Answer (score 1):

use /usr/bin/ for run pip. Example :

```
/usr/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

running this command solved the same problem for me (python 3.9):

```
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```